# What is the RXJS 6 way of handling http Observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I noticed that my code doesnt work when I use it in a new project:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { TypeAndCountURL } from '@app/constants';
import { HttpErrorService } from '@app/services/http-error.service';
import { TypeAndCountResponseBody, TypeAndCountRequestBody } from '@app/models/type-and-count/bodies.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor (private http: HttpClient, private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService) {}

  postTypeAndCountRequest(typeAndCountRequestBody: TypeAndCountRequestBody): Observable<TypeAndCountResponseBody> {
    return this.http.post<TypeAndCountResponseBody>(TypeAndCountURL, typeAndCountRequestBody).pipe(
      catchError(this.httpErrorService.handleError<TypeAndCountResponseBody>('postTypeAndCountRequest'))
    );

  }
}
```

specifically, I am getting `Cannot find name 'catchError'. Did you mean 'RTCError'?ts(2552)`

Reading up on this, I see that I can resolve the issue by importing it separately (from rxjs/operators .. whihc is fine, but) .. but also that this whole structure is compat mode for rxjs 5 ... what is the RXJS 6 way of handling the error response?

Comment: Since rxjs 6, all operators have to be imported separately. import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

Comment: I still need to use it at all? I was reading that the whole operator is on the path to deprecation...

Comment: You can remove the catchError operator and handle errors at the subscription level. e.g: myobservable.subscribe(result=>{...do something},error=>{...handle error})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

fetchUser() {
       this.userService.getProfile()
          .subscribe(
             (data: User) => this.userProfile = { ...data }
              , // success path
              error => this.error = error // error path
       );
    }
```

Comment: I noted in my OP that I am aware that I can do this but that this is described elsewhere as being an "old" way of doing it. I am asking for the new way.

Comment: @robertotomás check my answer again. You can handle error like mine. first callback will be result, second callback will be error handler

Comment: hey Tony, I thank you again for this answer -- I notice that it is becoming popular :) You might want to revise it to de-emphasize the old way, as that is not the substance of your post. Best